# Найти свободно реферала

Tags: php, mysql, рекурсия

есть структура как в таблице на картинке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у каждого пользователя есть свои уровни рефералов как на фото 2 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне найти пользователя(реферала, у которого нет дочки) например в ветке, которая начинается с id 3? пока я додумался как найти свободного реферала у которого нет дочки по все структуре:

```
SELECT min(t1.id) as refer, t1.parent_id, t1.user_id as us_id, t2.cnt
                        FROM modxev_programm_one as t1
                        LEFT JOIN 
                        (
                        SELECT parent_id, COUNT(parent_id) as cnt 
                        FROM modxev_programm_one
                        WHERE parent_id is not null
                        GROUP BY parent_id 
                        ) as t2
                        ON t1.id = t2.parent_id
                        WHERE t2.cnt > 0 and t2.cnt < 2
```

как сделать, чтобы поиск начинался от конкретного парента, например id=3?
без рекурсии и процедруы, так как хостинг этого не дает сделать, нужен vps хостинг

Comment: у одного человека может быть 2 реферала? Вам нужно найти тех, у кого 0 рефералов?

Comment: да, именно в ветке пользователя, у которого id в базе равен 3

Comment: хостинг, ограничивает в процедуре хранимой и в рекурсии

Answer (score 0):

написал вот такой алгоритм, выводит дерево для пользователя

```
<?php
$sql= "SELECT id, parent_id, user_id FROM modxev_programm_one";
$cats = array();
$statement = $modx->query($sql);
$parent = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($parent as $res) {
    $cats[$res['parent_id']][] =  $res;
}
function build_tree($cats,$parent_id){
if(is_array($cats) and count($cats[$parent_id])>0){
$tree = '<ul>';
 foreach($cats[$parent_id] as $cat){
  $tree .= '<li>'.$cat['user_id'];
 $tree .=  build_tree($cats,$cat['id']);
  $tree .= '</li>';         
 }
 $tree .= '</ul>';
  } 
  else return null;          
  return $tree; 
}
echo build_tree($cats,2);
```

а как теперь посчитать и вычислить у кого нет дочек либо одна?

Comment: а как для конкретного id?

Чтобы найти все id, у которых менее 2х рефералов:

SELECT id, cnt from (
SELECT id, (SELECT count (*) FROM modxev_programm_one t2 WHERE t2.parent_id=t1.id) AS cnt
FROM modxev_programm_one t1) x
WHERE x.cnt<2

Comment: предполагаю, что Ваш комментарий относится к моему ответу, но не могу его понять. как вы себе представляете - "найти все id, у которых менее 2х рефералов, для конкретного id"?

Comment: да, найти все id, у которых менее 2х рефералов, для конкретного id

Comment: все равно не могу понять...возможно, имеется ввиду, что для конкретного родительского id нужно найти все нижестоящие id, у которых менее 2х рефералов? если нет, то дайте пример...

Comment: да, это и имел ввиду - для конкретного родительского id нужно найти все нижестоящие id, у которых менее 2х рефералов

Comment: увы, с этим не помогу, учитывая ограничения, о которых Вы писали в задаче...попробуйте посмотреть тут https://club.shelek.ru/viewart.php?id=307

Comment: я написал рекурсию, структуру выводит, но вывести у которых одна дочка или нет не могу понять, выше в ответе я писал код

Comment: так у вас же ограничение - без рекурсии...

Comment: тот пример работает, например выводит всех моих дочек(2-х) и дочек моих дочек и т.д. И теперь мне нужно в таком цикле найти дочку у которой либо одна дочка либо 0 и эта дочка должна быть с наименьшим id в таблице

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы найти к-во рефералов у конкретного id:

```
SELECT id, (SELECT count (*) FROM modxev_programm_one t2 WHERE t2.parent_id=t1.id) AS cnt
FROM modxev_programm_one t1
WHERE id=3
```

Чтобы найти все id, у которых менее 2х рефералов:

```
SELECT id, cnt from (
SELECT id, (SELECT count (*) FROM modxev_programm_one t2 WHERE t2.parent_id=t1.id) AS cnt
FROM modxev_programm_one t1) x
WHERE x.cnt<2
```